# remove broken text from FileReader.readAsText results

Tags: javascript, text, extract, filereader, .doc

I am trying to read in .doc files using FileReader, and use it to extract the text.  Upon getting results I am getting a lot of broken characters, the first paragraph I get contains:
`��ࡱ�>��   !#���� ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Y  ��bjbj�W�W`

is there any way to just get the text written in the .doc file without all the formatting?

Comment: There's probably some way to do it, but it involves a lot of coding, and knowing exactly how a `.doc` file is structured

Comment: Look for a js library that can do this for you

Comment: From all the libraries I have found none of them will work in browser without fs